# html5 geolocation is not showing on mobile device #WiFi

Tags: html, mobile, geolocation, location, wifi

I have implemented Html5 geo-location.It works Good in system.
But when i used to run this on mobile device it's not working if my location service is turned off .

However my mobile devices is Connected through WiFi it is not showing location.It as to show something nearest point

```
function writeAddressName(latLng) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
          "location": latLng
        },
        function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
              document.getElementsByName("address").item(0).value  = results[0].formatted_address;

          else
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Unable to retrieve your address" + "<br />";
        });
      }

      function geolocationSuccess(position) {
        var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        // Write the formatted address
        writeAddressName(userLatLng);

        var myOptions = {
          zoom : 16,
          center : userLatLng,
          mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        // Draw the map
        var mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        // Place the marker
        new google.maps.Marker({
          map: mapObject,
          position: userLatLng
        });
      }

      function geolocationError(positionError) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Error: " + positionError.message + "<br />";
      }

      function geolocateUser() {
        // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
          var positionOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 10 * 1000 // 10 seconds
          };
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, positionOptions);
        }
        else
          document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API";
      }
      window.onload = geolocateUser;
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO, which phone/ platform are you using?

Comment: Iphone3gs checked in both #Safari #Chrome @Shiva

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information, please also share the code you are using